Can't install Stripe CLI onto VS Code
Ive downloaded the Stripe.exe, tried to use it from both \downloads and \system32 yet the results are still the same.
I launch it and login, and after being redirected to the webpage and clicking log in there I go to VS Code (where I've already downloaded the extension) to be greeted with the same message "Install Stripe CLI".
I've also tried to add a custom path, which also didn't work as VS Code could not find the .exe for some reason.
Does anyone have an idea why I cant install/login to the CLI?

Are you trying to install the CLI (https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-cli#install) or the Stripe VS Code extension (https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-vscode)?
What happens when you run stripe login in a plain terminal?

I've already got the VS Code extension, its the CLI that I'm having problems with. I tried in the terminal in VS Code but I got the same result as in command prompt.

Did you do step 3 in the guide?

Add the path to the unzipped stripe.exe file to your Path environment variable.

This is the guide they recommend to checking your Path env variable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.4&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.3#saving-changes-to-environment-variables

Yeah, I followed multiple tutorials on Youtube and everything works, yet VS Code still fails to see the CLI is installed even when doing it within VS Codes' terminal.

After repeating the same process three times, the fourth time magically worked. I have no idea what I done differently, but VS Code finally worked and I'm able to use Stripe. I kept changing the path to the stripe.exe file until it VS Code recognised it in /System32. Thanks for the help.
